# Display text file using MsgBox

Tags: arrays, vbscript, msgbox

I have multiple files with names:

```
c123we_1014_A1_45333
c123we_1014_A2_45333
c123we_1014_A3_45333
```

What I need is to get only the third parameter and display it using a message box.
What I do is I get the third parameter and write it in text file.

```
For Each filelog In FileList
    LogFile = Split(filelog, "~")(1)

    Set otf = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Data\" & LogFile, 1)

    sFile = Split(LogFile, "_")
    CurStep = sFile(3)

    FileNameStep = LotId & "_" & "Step"
    ScriptPath = Mid(ScriptFolder, 1, Len(ScriptFolder) - 8)

    If Not fso.FileExists(ScriptFolder & "\" & FileNameStep & ".txt") Then
        Set ctf = fso.CreateTextFile(ScriptFolder & "\" & FileNameStep & ".txt", True)
        ctf.Close
    End If

    Set otf = fso.OpenTextFile(ScriptFolder & "\" & FileNameStep & ".txt", 8)
    otf.Writeline "Current - " & CurStep
    otf.Close
Next
```

My text file output will be as below:

```
Current - A1
Current - A2
Current - A3
```

I am stuck at how to display the content of text file using message box.

I have also tried using array instead write it to txt file which more simpler that using txt file.  My code as below:

```
For Each filelog In FileList
    LogFile = Split(filelog, "~")(1)

    Set otf = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Data\" & LogFile, 1)

    l = 0
    MsgBox FileList.Count
    Do While l < FileList.Count 
        sFile = Split(LogFile, "_")
        CurStep = sFile(4)

        array.Add CurStep 

        l = l + 1
    Loop
Next

MsgBox Join(array, vbNewLine)
```

But got error. The error is at `MsgBox Join()` line:

> Error: Invalid procedure call or argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have written the data to your text file you can close it and then follow these steps:

A. Open the file in Read mode again and set an object reference to it:

```
Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(ScriptFolder & "\" & FileNameStep & ".txt",1)
```

B. Read the contents of the file using the **readall()** method and store it in a variable:

```
tempData = objFile.readAll()
```

C. Close the file and Display the contents using 'Msgbox'

```
objFile.Close
MsgBox tempData
```

If you want to display the data in text file, line-by-line you can use the **readline()** method and modify step B to:

```
While not fso.atEndOfStream
    tempData = fso.readline()
    Msgbox tempData
Wend
```

Edit 2: For the second part of your question:

You should not  use the word "array" as a variable name as it is a keyword in vbscript. Also, you do not add elements in an array using .Add as we are talking about arrays here not arraylists.

You can replace your code with the following:

```
Dim intCtr: intCtr=-1
Dim tempArr()
For Each filelog in FileList    
LogFile = Split(filelog, "~")(1)

Set otf = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Data\" & LogFile, 1)

     l = 0
    msgbox FileList.Count
    do while l < FileList.Count 
        intCtr=intCtr+1
        sFile = Split(LogFile, "_")
        CurStep = sFile(4)
        Redim preserve tempArr(intCtr)
        tempArr(intCtr)=CurStep 
        l = l + 1
    Loop
next

MsgBox Join(tempArr, vbNewLine)
```

Comment: thank you. this code works perfectly fine. actually, i have another question, how to display array in msgbox?

Comment: `MsgBox Join(array, vbNewLine)`

Comment: ive already tried this before but got error. the error is "invalid procedure call or argument"

Comment: For that we need to see the contents of your array. I cannot see any array in the code you have posted.

Comment: @Kira i have tried you code, its working but the output double. The output `A1 A1 A2 A2 A3 A3` . It should only `A1 A2 A3`

Comment: There may be a problem in your logic. You only asked for how to add elements to array and display them. Debug and find out where the issue is in your code.